# Flex 4 - CSS type selectors in MXML components

Tags: css, components, mxml, flex4, css-selectors

Does anybody know the reason why CSS type selectors cannot be used inside MXML components, and/or a trick to make it work?

I see absolutely no reason for a such simple functionnality not to be supported, and I'd really like to understand.

After all I read about CSS in Flex 4 being so much better than in Flex 3, I find myself quite disapointed when I'm forced to repeat myself, addding the same parameter to all my buttons...

```
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        .sampleStyle {   color: red;   }        
    </fx:Style>

    <s:Button label="1" styleName="sampleStyle"/>
    <s:Button label="2" styleName="sampleStyle"/>
    <s:Button label="3" styleName="sampleStyle"/>
```

...while I could simply use a type selector and keep my MXML code a lot cleaner and readable.

```
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        s|Button {   color: red;   }        
    </fx:Style>

    <s:Button label="1"/>
    <s:Button label="2"/>
    <s:Button label="3"/>
```

I didn't found any information on this issue (apart from Adobe documentation which basically just says "*that's not possible*"), but I'd really like to know the reason behind this.
Is there something I don't get, or are these selectors actually totally useless?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem! I needed to override the default text color in TextInputs. You can edit the master css file:

```
my|Component s|Button {
    color: red;
}
```